# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, string, indexoutofboundsexception

This a code for converting hex to string but it works fine until size of the string doesn't exceeds 62 characters?

```
public static String hexToString(String hex)
        {       
           StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
           for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i+=2)
           {
            String str = hex.substring(i, i+2);
            output.append((char)Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
           }
           return(output.toString());
        }
```

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   62
>                 at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
>                 at HEX.hexToString(HEX.java:36)
>                 at HEX.main(HEX.java:56)

Comment: it must be in the input, give us example

Comment: String hex1 = "234c02ecbbfbafa3ed18510abd11fa724fcda2018a1a8342cf064bbde548d"

Comment: It's 61 characters and in last iteration of your for cycle you ask for characters 61+62.. That is the problem. What are you actually trying to achieve??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will face this problem only when you have odd number of characters in your string. Fix your function as follows:

```
public static String hexToString(String hex)
    {       
       StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
       String str = "";
       for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i+=2)
       {

        if(i+2 < hex.length()){
            str = hex.substring(i, i+2);
        }else{
            str = hex.substring(i, i+1);
        }
        output.append((char)Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
       }
       return(output.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`i+2` in `String str = hex.substring(i, i+2);` is the problem. even if `i < hex.length()`, `i+2` is too large if `hex.length()` is odd.

Answer (score 0):

If youre using String.length in a for loop with i initiated at 0 then you need to -1 from the strings length

```
for (int i = 0; i < hex.length()-1; i+=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your loop condition :

```
for (int i = 0; i < hex.length() - 3; i +=2)
```

Comment: that's too simple. i < hex.length()-3, then i+2 < hex.length()-1, that's not what the OP wants